# IBM Cloud Code Engine: How to get IP addresses for my app, so that I can allowlist it?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, whitelist, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have an IBM Cloud Code Engine project with a deployed container app. That app needs to access a protected resource. I need to configure an allowlist and add the IP address(es) for the app.

How do I find those IP addresses? Is there an official list?

Answer (score 5):

I found the following API function for IBM Cloud Code Engine to [list egress IP addresses](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/codeengine/v2#get-project-egress-ips).

In a shell and with the IBM Cloud CLI with Code Engine plugin, I performed the following steps:

- log in to IBM Cloud
- `ibmcloud iam oauth-tokens --output json` to obtain the access token
- `ibmcloud ce project list` to obtain the Code Engine project ID and region of my project
- `curl -X GET "https://api.REGION.codeengine.cloud.ibm.com/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/egress_ips" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN"`  replace the parameters and call the API function

The list of returned IP addresses needs to be added in the allowlist.

Comment: Yes, there is no a single static IP rather a range of IPs. Consider that Code Engine is built on top of Kubernetes.